# How to navigate textboxes in between different tables using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, it is working that is navigating between the textboxes, but the issue is it is navigating only within one table, but am having different tables in my page. How to make it work?

```
$('input[type="text"],textarea').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which==39 || e.which==13)
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
    else if(e.which==37 || e.which==8)
        $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
    else if(e.which==40 || e.which==13)
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
    else if(e.which==38 || e.which==8)
        $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
});




    <form>
   <table width="960" align="center" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="15" id="navigate"> 
            <thead>                 
                <th align="center"></th>
                <th align="center"></th>
                <th align="center"></th>
                <th align="center"></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="font-size:15px;"><b>ADVERTISING:</b></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
                <th align="center">DOMESTIC($)</th>
                <th align="center">INTERNATIONAL($)</th>
                <th align="center">NOTES</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="spending_table_title" title="<?php echo $this->data[14]->content; ?>"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $this->data[13]->content; ?></span></td>
                    <td ><input type="text" value="" name="actual_marketing_dom_print" id="actual_marketing_dom_print"  size="30" style="height:20px; width:155px;" onChange="total_dom_advt();total_marketing_spending();format(this);"/> </td>
                    <td ><input type="text" value="" name="actual_marketing_intl_print" id="actual_marketing_intl_print"  size="30" style="height:20px; width:155px; " onChange="total_intl_advt();total_marketing_spending();format(this);"/></td>
                    <td ><textarea name="actual_marketing_print_notes"  id="actual_marketing_print_notes" style="height:32px; width:300px;" rows="3" cols="20"  class ="notes"> </textarea></td>
                </tr>


                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                 <br>

         <br>         

         <div class="divgrid">

         <table width="960" align="center" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="15" id="navigate"> 
            <thead>
                <th style="width:60%;"></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">TOTAL PRESS AND PUBLIC RELATIONS (DOMESTIC AND INTERNATIONAL COMBINED):</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th align="center">$</th>
            <th align="center">NOTES</th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  class="spending_table_title" title="<?php echo $this->data[31]->content; ?>"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $this->data[30]->content; ?></span></td>

               <td ><input type="text" value="" name="actual_marketing_industry_relations" id="actual_marketing_industry_relations"  size="30" style="height:20px; width:155px; " onChange="total_press_public();total_marketing_spending();format(this);"/></td>
                    <td ><textarea name="actual_marketing_industry_relations_notes"  id="actual_marketing_industry_relations_notes" style="height:32px; width:300px;" rows="3" cols="20" class ="notes"> </textarea></td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
         </table>
</form>
```

in my code am having two tables, after completing the textboxes in one table am not table to navigate to next table textboxes, i was not known how to do this

Comment: Could you add some code you tried to solve this problem with?

Comment: really i was not known how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question, and hopefully you will find this helpful.

What I'm doing here is to check if there is an `input` above or below to go to with `if (t.length == 0)`, and if not, move to the corresponding cell in the next or previous `table` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"],textarea').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 39) {
            $(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
        } else if (e.which == 37) {
            $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input[type="text"],textarea').focus();
        } else if (e.which == 40) {
            var t = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input[type="text"],textarea');
            if (t.length == 0) {
                t = $(document).find('table:eq(' + ($('table').index($(this).closest('table')) + 1) + ')').find('tbody tr td').parent().first().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input[type="text"]:not([readonly]),textarea');
            }
            t.focus();
        } else if (e.which == 38) {
            var t = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input[type="text"],textarea');
            if (t.length == 0) {
                t = $(document).find('table:eq(' + ($('table').index($(this).closest('table')) - 1) + ')').find('tbody tr td').parent().last().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input[type="text"]:not([readonly]),textarea');
            }
            t.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zxTfb/5/

Please note that right now, this only works on multiple tables on top of each other, not side by side. If you need them side by side, you could copy what I did for keys `40` and `38` and modify it to work for `39` and `37` as well.

Hope it helps.

**Further explanation**

Let's break down this line of code and look at inner workings:

```
t = $(document).find('table:eq(' + ($('table').index($(this).closest('table')) - 1) + ')').find('tbody tr td').parent().last().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input[type="text"]:not([readonly]),textarea');
```

First we find the table above the one we are currently in. This is done with the selector `:eq()` which selects an element, `table` in this case, by it's index. We select the `table` with our current tables index `-1` to get the table above.

```
$(document).find('table:eq(' + ($('table').index($(this).closest('table')) - 1) + ')')
```

Now that we have the table above our current position, we find the last `<tr>` element that **does** contain a `<td>`, by first looking for all `<td>`, then move up to it's parent `<tr>` with `.parent()` and finally select the last one (bottom row) with `.last()`.

```
.find('tbody tr td').parent().last()
```

Now we know which `<tr>` to look in, so we move ahead and look for the specific `<td>` by index, so that we end up in the right column, corresponding to the one we are currently in. This is similar to when we found the `<table>` by index at the top.

```
.find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')')
```

Finally, we now have our correct `<td>` element and now all that remains is to find our `<input>` or `<textarea>` that isn't readonly. We do this simply by selecting them like so

```
.find('input[type="text"]:not([readonly]),textarea');
```

And now we know where to move in the table above. Since we set `t` to this new element, all that remains is to move the focus there with `t.focus()`.

And there you have it!

Comment: this works for the tables like before, but the table code is updated above in the code, for that code it is not working.

Comment: Updated my answer to ignore elements between the tables. http://jsfiddle.net/zxTfb/1/

Comment: Ah, just noticed my example didn't include `textarea`, only `input`. Easy fix at the end of each line. I'll update my answer.

Comment: i think it is because of tbody, thead like that

Comment: Try it now. `tbody` and `thead` should be ignored.

Comment: i have added text area and tried but its not working with my code

Comment: yes they are to be ignored but it is not moving to next table in my code

Comment: This was a tricky one, but I think I got it. Updated my answer with new code again.

Comment: hi engdal for the code i have updated now, for this it is not working, i was not known what was the reason for this

Comment: It's most likely because you have added `<th>` tags in `<tbody>` that wasn't there before. It's hard to make this work in any given situation, so you probably have to decide what pattern you want and make it work for that.

Comment: Here is an update to cover the `<th>` issue as well, but please don't change it anymore ;) http://jsfiddle.net/zxTfb/5/

Comment: I updated my post with a detailed explanation, so that you can see what's going on in the code and modify it for any future changes. Good luck!

Comment: i found the issue, thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

Use a global counter to assign IDs to your inputs. Then, since you know what ID triggered the event, you just add or subtract from that ID to get the new ID you should go to. Here's some code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("hej");
  $('input[type="text"],textarea').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which==39 || e.which==13) {
        var thisId = parseInt(this.id);
        $("#" + (thisId + 1)).focus();
    } else if(e.which==37 || e.which==8) {
        var thisId = parseInt(this.id);
        $("#" + (thisId - 1)).focus();
    } else if(e.which==40 || e.which==13) {
        var thisId = parseInt(this.id);
        $("#" + (thisId + 4)).focus();
    } else if(e.which==38 || e.which==8) {
        var thisId = parseInt(this.id);
        $("#" + (thisId - 4)).focus();
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <form>
<table>

 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="1" name="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="2" name="6"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="3" name="7"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="4" name="8"></td>


 </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="5" name="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="6" name="6"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="7" name="7"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="8" name="8"></td>


 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="9" name="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="10" name="6"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="11" name="7"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="12" name="8"></td>


 </tr>

</table>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="13" name="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="14" name="6"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="15" name="7"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="16" name="8"></td>


 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="17" name="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="18" name="6"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="19" name="7"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="20" name="8"></td>


 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="21" name="5"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="22" name="6"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="23" name="7"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="24" name="8"></td>


 </tr>

</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```